# Page not opening but URL is entered in browser in Selenium Java with Cucumber Automation

Tags: pageload

I am able to open a URL manually in CHROME and FIREFOX.
But, Unable to open the Page in Automation using Selenium Java with Cucumber.
Page opens once in like 10 attempts.

URL is getting entered in the address bar but Page is not opening.
If I refresh once or twice, the page is opening in the same Launched browser through Automation.

Others are able to open the page with same code in Automation.

> Errors:  Getting NoSuchElementException exception because the page is
> NOT opening.

I am using Below:
latest Chrome 120.0.6099.200 version and Firefox 121.0 version,
Cucumber,
Maven project,
Eclipse IDE
Selenium Version 4.5.0

I tried

- restarting Chrome browser
- clearing cache
- reinstalling the browser.
- tried running from Command Prompt.